# GitLab runner network

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm using gitlab runner on a EKS cluster, registered to GitLab (hosted elsewhere, not in my cluster) and I don't understand how their network works.

When there's a new job to be executed, other pods are created but I don't get how they can do anything as there's no services associated with them. How can they reach the outside to clone the repo and send back the report?

Comment: pods don't need services to reach the internet, kubernetes services are for Ingres traffic, not Egress traffic

Comment: Yep, I deleted the service to try and it's still working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/#runner-execution-flow

Actually the Runner talks to the executor, in this case Kubernetes. The executor is the one cloning the repository.